# Passing form value in joomla

Tags: forms, joomla

I would like to upgrade one of my joomla 2.5 plugin (self-developed). It is a complex task, but here is this specific issue I couldn't solve. I would like to put an input field with a submit button at my articles (done), and after submitting I want to get it. So simple.

Here is the outline of the code:

The form:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="info">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
    </form>
```

The process:

```
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $foo = $jinput->get('info', '444'); 
    print_r($foo);
```

Basically it should work, but somehow I don't get the value, always recive the default value '444'. If I change the action to an external php file, and process in php-way, it works.

What I checked so far:

a. change form method to GET. Result: the needed value appears properly in the article's URL, but still print the default value '444' not the value I see in the URL (if the default value isn't set, it doesn't print anything).

b. pass the value to an external .php file, store in session, and echo the session value in the article, but empty again.

Maybe I will force to get the GET values by exploding the $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], but I can't sleep until I find out what could be wrong with desired process.

Anyone can help?

UPDATE: maybe important - I use K2 plugin.

Comment: Interesting. Can you `print_r($jinput)` or even `JFactory::getApplication()->input->post` and check the value there?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the timing of the event that triggers the plugin. Maybe the input or output is requested after the plugin is deployed or something...

Comment: Can you check if $_POST['info'] works?

Comment: the trigger is onK2beforeDisplay. I tried with onK2PrepareContent but nothing.

Comment: Dmitry: the value is empty.

Comment: di3sel: no $_POST['info'] doesn't work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I could figure out the following:

it is a special case. On my local server the code works fine both with normal joomla articles and K2 component articles.

on my website the code also works fine with normal joomla articles, so it is defenietly a K2 settigns-issue.

there was a chance the problem is related to K2 advanced SEF settings (specifies the url of the K2 item), but it isn't. The problem is on my website, so I used on my localhost-version the SEF settings of the website-version, and I recived the values fine. == not K2 advanced SEF settings problem.

This is the answer for my question: "should find which K2 setting is causing the problem"

UPDATE. Solution: turn off caching at global configuration, so the page isn't loading from cache. In cache are no given values stored - obbbbbviously.

Comment: On my localhost I'm not receiving any POST data when the root does't end with slash and there are .htaccess rewriterules used: `http://localhost/projects/test`. Did you try using other key than `info` ?

Comment: thanks the comment piotr_cz, I did try with other keys as well - no effects. The .htaccess-thing: I don't think it's up to the .htaccess file, because I placed the code in content.php too (to check if my code works on regural joomla articles) and it worked. So it's defenietly an K2 specific issue

Comment: Maybe K2 is overwriting the `JInput` values? What about `$_POST` and `JRequest::getVar('info')`.

Comment: I am convinced K2 is overwriting the JInput values, but where? Getting more and more frustrated :) `$_POST` and `JRequest::getVar()` are also empty

Comment: The issue must be somewhere between the component part and the template part. If I put the `echo JURI::getInstance()->toString();` line file by file at the component library, it returns the whole value. When i do this with template files, it returns only the core URI.  Shit isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the `$_SERVER` values get overwritten too somewhere in `$app->dispatch()`

Comment: H-A-L-L-E-L-U-J-A-H!!! Luckily yesterday my page suffered a massif virus attack. When I restored the site from backup, I noticed how huge is my com_k2 cache libray. Why is it important anyway - asked myself. Then I get suspicious, maybe caching ignores the GET/POST/SESSION/etc. values. So I turned caching off, and yes indeed, this solved the problem.

Comment: Good for you. Sounds like a bug in K2/ Joomla